# Hibernate - one to one mapping using annotations

Tags: java, hibernate

I want to map class address to class employee,  What I have done till yet is as below.

My employee class

```
@Entity(name = "EMPLOYEE")
public class Employee  {
    @Id @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name="EMPLOYEEID", length =30)
    int id;
    public Employee(String string, String string2,String string3, String string4) {
    this.name=string;
    this.age=string2;
    }
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    @Column(name="NAME", length = 30)
    String name;
    @Column(name="AGE",  length = 30)
    String age;
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "employee", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    Address address;
    public Address getAddress() {
        return address;
    }
    public void setAddress(Address address) {
        this.address = address;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getAge() {
        return age;
    }
    public void setAge(String age) {
        this.age = age;
    }
```

and my address class is

```
@Entity(name="Address")
public class Address {
    @Id
    @Column(name="EMPLOYEEID", length =30)
    @GenericGenerator(name="generator", strategy="foreign", parameters = @Parameter(name="property", value="employee"))
    @GeneratedValue(generator="generator")
    int id;
    @Column(name="LINE1", length=30)
    String line1;
    @Column(name="LINE2", length=30)
    String line2;
    @Column(name="LINE3", length=30)
    String line3;
    public String getLine1() {
        return line1;
    }
    public void setLine1(String line1) {
        this.line1 = line1;
    }
    public String getLine2() {
        return line2;
    }
    public void setLine2(String line2) {
        this.line2 = line2;
    }
    public String getLine3() {
        return line3;
    }
    public void setLine3(String line3) {
        this.line3 = line3;
    }
}
```

But whenever I'm trying to execute it I'm getting the error

> Unknown mappedBy in: com.hibernatetest.company.Employee.address, referenced property unknown: com.hibernatetest.company.Address.employee

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You need to have an employee reference in your Address domain model as it is searching for property named "employee" in Address class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You referenced non-existent property of `Address`:

```
@OneToOne(mappedBy = "employee", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
Address address;
```

Check out the docs for [OneToOne.mappedBy()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/OneToOne.html#mappedBy()):

> (Optional) The field that owns the relationship. This element is only specified on the inverse (non-owning) side of the association.

So, your code states that `Address` entity has a field `employee` that owns the relationship. But it doesn't have a property like this.

Probably you can implement this property with the following code (DISCLAIMER: I didn't test it and I dont' know if it's suits your particular situation):

```
@OneToOne(optional=false)
@JoinColumn(name="EMPLOYEEID")
Employee employee;

public Employee getEmployee() {
     return employee;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your are getting unknown because you have given small letter employee which is not defined any where try changing it to

```
@OneToOne(mappedBy = "EMPLOYEE", cascade = CascadeType.ALL) here
```

Comment: Did you change the below one too.
@Parameter(name="property", value="employee")